# PHP: Override a service-provider that calls a method that's not in my Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have an old website which was developed in Laravel 5.2 and which for various reasons can't be upgraded from that.

I have a vendor package which, in the `boot()` method of one `ServiceProvider`, has this line:

```
 $this->loadMigrationsFrom($somewhere);
```

... but this method did not exist in Laravel 5.2.

What would be the *cleanest* way to override this errant method-call?

It occurs to me that I might just be able to write a new service-provider class to replace this one, since all it *really* seems to do is to register one console command.  But is there a way to "override" it?

Comment: I think you'll just need to restrict the dependency versions in your composer.json file a bit more to prevent the version of ServiceProvider that requires `loadMigrationsFrom`

Comment: *Hmmmm...* hoping that there is such a version, and that the call wasn't in there all along? ... ... Well, that turns out not to be such a good idea given the nature of this package.  Looks like the developer made a lot of changes to it over time and I don't want to go back into those changes.  Adding a call to "loadMigrationsFrom()" turns out to be just one change among a very great many.  Thanks for the idea, though.

Answer (score 0):

In this case I was able to bypass the problem by creating a new ServiceProvider and using it instead of the vendor's version in `config/app.php`.